# KoGrid: Accessing the selectedItemCount

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kogrid

I am trying to create a binding to the selectedItemCount of a KoGrid (similar to how they do it in the kgFooter). However, when I try:

```
<input type="button" value="View" data-bind="enable: selectedItemCount > 0"></input>
```

I'm getting a reference error about "selectedItemCount is not defined;". How am I supposed to bind to this variable? I also tried selectedItems.length but that is also undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check example of how use it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PrkR8/)

Basically there are two extra binding properties that you should use:

for multiselect:

```
<div id="sandBox" class="example" style="height: 300px; width: 600px;" 
     data-bind="koGrid: { data: myObsArray, selectedItems: selected }">
</div>
```

or if you are allowing to select only one item:

```
<div id="sandBox" class="example" style="height: 300px; width: 600px;" 
     data-bind="koGrid: { data: myObsArray, selectedItem: selected }">
</div>
```

So in first case you have to declare property `viewModel.selected = ko.observableArray([])` and in second case `viewModel.selected = ko.observable()`

Also check this read-only koGrid binding configuration on [github](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid/wiki/Configuration)